# Confused by convention in paho-mqtt for asigning a built in method as a function that i create (but without arguments)

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am trying to get my head around the paho-MQTT library. I am struggling to understand what is clearly a convention in the coding of the library, but which doesn't make sense to me. I am happy to look this up, if someone can give me the topic I should be looking for.

A lot of paho-mqtt tutorials and PAHO Foundation page (https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#constructor-reinitialise) talk about handling the `on_message`, and `on_connect` methods (or at least what i think are methods) for the `Client` object. The tutorials all provide a standard way to engage with these methods, but in a way that I can't understand. It goes as follows:

Define a function that takes a set number of arguments. Something like:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message):  
    print(message.payload, 'on', message.topic)
```

The process then is to create an 'mqtt Client' object and connect it to the broker. After that, to see the messages that client is subscribed to, i do the following:

```
client.on_message = on_message
```

This is this part that I don't understand. I understand this as meaning I am assigning a method the value of a function (but without calling its arguments or indicating its a function). I would have thought that `client.on_message` would have returned a 3 tupple, that I would have accessed via the function above, as follows:

```
on_message(client.on_message)
```

When I call `type(client.on_message)` I get `NoneType` back, indicating that `mqtt.Client.on_message` doesn't return anything. This explains why i can't call my function on the method.

Perhaps this is just a syntax issue, but could someone explain the convention here (or tell me what i should be looking up). Is `Client.on_message` a method of the class mqtt.Client? and how am I assigning it the value of a function I defined without providing any arguments, despite specifying arguments when I defined them? Further, how am I assigning the function without indicating the parenthesis (`on_message()`)?

Below is a full bit of working code for paho-mqtt:

```
#import the library
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt 

#Write the function to get the payload content (i.e. the text) from the message object
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print('Recieved message', str(message.payload))

#create the mqtt object and connect to the broker
MQTT_BROKER = [broker-IP]
client = mqtt.Client('Client1')
client.connect(MQTT_BROKER)

#subscribe to the topic
client.subscribe('TEST_TOPIC')

#Somehow invoke the function defined above on the mqtt on.message method - i.e. what i don't understand
client.on_message = on_message

#Do this continually so i can keep looking for messages published on this topic
client.loop_forever()
```

The problem I am having is that i still can't see messages in the console, on the topic to which I am subscribed. I know these are being published elsewhere (on another client) because I can see them on the broker when running `mosquitto_sub -t 'TEST_TOPIC'`.

At the moment I am just trying to understand the convention so that I can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

You will never explicitly call any of the callback functions. The client will call them from it's event loop at the appropriate time.

`client.on_message = on_message` is how yo tell the client which function to call (in the future) when a message arrives. Passing a function name with no arguments passes a handle to the function it's self.

Similar with the `on_connect` function, this is a function that the client will call once it has completed connecting to the broker.

I have re-arranged your code to ensure things are done in the right order using the `on_connect` callback to subscribe to the topic once it has finished connecting.

```
#import the library
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt 

#Write the function to get the payload content (i.e. the text) from the message object
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print('Recieved message', str(message.payload))

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    #subscribe to the topic
    client.subscribe('TEST_TOPIC')

#create the mqtt object and connect to the broker
MQTT_BROKER = [broker-IP]
client = mqtt.Client('Client1')
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(MQTT_BROKER)

#Do this continually so i can keep looking for messages published on this topic
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: thanks for this and the updates to my script. I understand that `client.on_message = on.message` tells the client to call the function i wrote above, but where am i getting the input for that function? Is `client.on_connect` a built in function of the `mqtt.Client` object? If its returning None how do i generate the variables for my `on_message()` function? Apologies if this is out of scope. I am trying to understand the convention being invoked here.

Comment: You don't. The client creates and passes all the required inputs for the callbacks. And the none of the callbacks return anything (because if they did it would be to the client loop, so no where you could access them anyway. If you want to use the incoming message payloads then to start with you need to look at python global variables

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Appreciate you walking me through this. For anyone else looking at this, useful guides also here:  http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-python-callbacks/ and here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-invoking-functions-with-and-without-parentheses/